# conditional inside a pgfplotsinvokeforeach loop

Tags: pgfplots, conditionals, loops

I'm using `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` to do mathematical computations inside the `\addplot` options. Now I need a conditional to decide whether to plot a line or not depending on the current index of the loop, but I can't do it by means of an `\ifthenelse` command.
Here is just a "pseudo"-example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {0.1,0.2,...,2}
    {\ifthenelse{#1<1}{\addplot {0};}{"do nothing"}}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get "missing =" and "missing number" errors.

The original (misleading) posted code was:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {0,...5}
    {\ifthenelse{#1<3}{\addplot {0};}{\addplot {1};}}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Would saying `{0,1,...,5}` instead of the wrong `{0,...5}` help?

Comment: egeg, I'm sorry but I don't know how to answer directly to your comment. You're right (I did a mistake in writing the code), but try with `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0.1,0.2}`. I get "missing =" and "missing number" errors. I need to handle both natural and rational numbers. Thank you

Comment: @Emily I've converted your 'answer' to a comment, and also merged your accounts. Please consider registering: that way you will have better control over your messages here.

Comment: @Joseph Wright, thank you. percusse showed me that my piece of code was a bit misleading. Shoud I modify it (and correct the mistake), or shoud I leave it as it is?

Comment: @Emily Please edit your question - the site works best if changes are edited into the questions/answers when appropriate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As egreg spotted, the coordinate list is missing a comma. Moreover, you can also use PGF `ifthenelse` for your task.

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach {0,...,5}
        {
    \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(#1<3,0,1)}
    \addplot coordinates {(#1,\pgfmathresult)};
    }
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Another possibility is to use the following for conditional plotting

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {0.1,0.2,...,1}
    {
\pgfmathparse{( #1 < 0.5 ? int(1) : int(0))}
\ifnum\pgfmathresult>0
\addplot{#1};
\else
\fi
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Notice how `0.5` slipped away from the if clause (only gets caught after `x<0.499975`). So please keep in mind that numerical accuracy is not that reliable.

[image]

Comment: You're right, but those plot commands were only example codes. The real question is how to plot a line or not (at all) depending on the loop index. Something like "if k<1 plot the line, else don't plot it". Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works well with natural numbers, but not with rational ones (try \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0.1,0.2} instead). I get the "missing =" and "missing number" errors.

Comment: @Emily I think this time it's getting there.

Comment: percusse you're right. Thank you very much (even for the explanation on accuracy)